# How to Solve AngularJS HTTP Post Function Return value

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i executed $Http.Post method to call c# Web-method to bind dropdown/Grid and etc by AnularJS, i would like make a single Common Http.post method to call all request, the function working fine but Data not bind or Return for objects

> Here My Code:-

```
function Http_Common(url, prcName, paramstr )
               var post = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { procedureName: prcName, paramstr: paramstr },
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                });

                post.success(function (data, status) {
                    return $.parseJSON(data.d);
                });
}
```

> Here I Call Http_Common function:-

```
 var data = Http_Common('Login.aspx/GetRowData_Tables', 'Dbsp_GET', 1);
```

here Http_Common function working fine and call C# Web-method, only issue data is not returning to variable or objects on to utilise

So anybody have idea to solve?.

> Here My Full Working Code Sample:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.ButtonClick = function () {

                var paramstr = '';
                paramstr = "@Month$" + 1 + '~';
                paramstr += "@Year$" + 2018 + '~';
                paramstr += "@StateID$" + 0 + '~';
                paramstr += "@HubID$" + 0 + '~';
                paramstr += "@BranchID$" + 0 + '~';
                paramstr += "@EmpID$" + 0 + '~';
                paramstr += "@EmpTypeID$" + 0 + '~';
                paramstr += "@UserID$" + 1 + '~';
                paramstr += "@UserTypeID$" + 1;

                var post = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "Login.aspx/GetRowData_Tables",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { procedureName: 'DBSP_MM_Rpt_AttendanceMonthWsie', paramstr: paramstr },
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                });

                post.success(function (data, status) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                    var datafields = new Array();
                    var source = { datatype: "json", datafields: datafields, localdata: data };
                    var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                    {
                        width: '98%',
                        height: '450px',
                        source: adapter,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        theme: 'energyblue',
                        pageable: true,
                        columnsresize: true,
                        pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', '15', '20', '100'],
                        pagesize: 15,
                        pagermode: 'default',
                        enabletooltips: true,
                        columns: get_cols(data)
                    });
                });

                post.error(function (data, status) {
                    $window.alert(data.Message);
                });
            }

        });
```

the above code working Fine and generate JQX Grid So $Http.post method not an issue, only when I create common $http.post function to call all my Request 
that time only Data not return or bind to $scope variable but method Execute and Return from Server, The Issues is after post.success data not return or bind to $scope variable

Comment: This looks more like jQuery. There is no `dataType` option in AngularJS.

Comment: Usually you won't server call a view page, `Login.aspx` with additional `/GetRow...` action. You mind editing your post and add the relevant controller name + complete action you try to bind to. Additionally debugging the desired action will help a lot solving your issues.

Comment: $http.post work and return data from Server, only Issue after post.success execute return data not assign to variable or $scope.sample variable this is Issue

Comment: function Http_Common(url, prcName, paramstr )
               var post = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { procedureName: prcName, paramstr: paramstr },
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                });

                post.success(function (data, status) {
                    return $.parseJSON(data.d);
                });
}

Comment: Have you tried to log the data value?

Comment: ya I tried var object as well as $scope.Sample Variable ,localstroage.setitem objects etc..,

Answer (score 0):

First your **Http_Common** return nothing. The return instruction is in the success callback.

The AngularJS $http service always return promise when you call any mathod.

For your case, you have to set the value of data variable when the success callback is called like this:

```
post.success(function(data){
 data = data.d;
```

})

You must use the data binding concept to share data from controller to view like this:

```
post.success(function(data){
 $scope.data = data.d;
```

})

You can return the post object in your Http_Common function and call the success callback in your controller.

Comment: ya sound good, i tried all your possibilities. like var data, $scope.data, even i tried localstroage.setitem whatever possible option but there is no fruitfull

Comment: Tri to log the data value returned when you call success callback

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [built-in callback methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for success/error handling

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Login.aspx/GetRowData_Tables",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { procedureName: 'DBSP_MM_Rpt_AttendanceMonthWsie', paramstr: paramstr },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

`.then()` will be invoked when the server responds. THe first function will be executed if the response is successful, the second one will be executed in case of error.